# plot.background only shows 3 out of 4 lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I'm experiencing a problem when using ggplot. my code shoud afaik give me a frame around the whole plot using (plot.background = element_rect(color="black"). However I only get 3 out of four lines. Any ideas on how to get 4 out of 4?

I have this theme:

```
theme.plot.bar <- function(){

 theme(
text                   = element_text(family = "sans", face = "plain", colour = "black", size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9),
axis.text.x            = element_text(size = 13, colour = "black"),
axis.text.y            = element_text(size = 11, colour = "black"),
strip.text             = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
axis.text.x            = element_text(vjust = 1),
axis.text.y            = element_text(hjust = 1), 
axis.ticks             = element_blank(),
axis.title.x           = element_text(), 
axis.title.y           = element_text(angle = 90),
panel.background       = element_rect(fill = NA ,colour = NA),
panel.grid.major.x     = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor       = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y     = element_line(colour = "black", linetype= "dotted", size =0.6),
strip.text.x           = element_text(),
strip.text.y           = element_text(angle = -90),
plot.background        = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype= 1, fill="white"), # Kant i højre side kommer ikke med hvis den sættes?
plot.margin            = unit(c(0, 1, 0, 0), "cm"),
complete               = FALSE)

}
```

Which gives me this output with ggplot:

[image]

EDIT: with plot.margin changed to 3 cm:
[image]

EDIT 2: with session info and ggplot-code as requested
NB: It still dont work when setting all plot margings as 2 inhes. I use png

sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
x              <- factor(pol$job_komp_v2)
df             <- as.data.frame(na.omit(x))
names(df)      <- "v1"
farve          <- rgb(144,26,30, maxColorValue =255)

r <- ggplot(df,aes(x=v1)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
fill=farve, width=0.35) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, "", limits=c(0,1), breaks= c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)) +
scale_x_discrete(name= "") +
theme.plot.bar()
r
```

Comment: I suspect your plot margins are too small, and the plot is cropped on the side

Comment: But even when I change the plot.margin to 20 cm it only gives me 3 out of 4. I am not sure what you mean with my plottet is too cropped? I just put another picture with the plot.margin being 3 cm in my example

Comment: did you change the 4 sides, eg `plot.margin=unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "in")`? It works for me. Post your sessionInfo() and the code you use to make a minimal plot too. What device are you using? Try another one, e.g pdf, or quartz, etc.

Comment: You can also try to increase size to 1 in plot.background=. Works for me when saved as png with ggsave()

Comment: Just posted what you requested baptiste

Comment: @Didziz Elferts: That actually worked. I thought that was just the thikness of the line..

Comment: @Einnor It is thickness of line, only you set it so small that somehow left line wasn't visible (something with margins and croping)